# Getting out of a loop with several IF conditions in pythons

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, selenium, for-loop

i'm new with python and selenium and im having some dificulties with this:

```
hosts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('hostname')

    noreportar = ['text','text1','text2','text3']
    lista = []
    noreportables =[]

    for i in hosts:

        if i.text in noreportar:
            noreportables.append(i.text)

        if i.text not in noreportar:
            lista.append(i.text)

    print lista
```

the result is :

```
[]
[]
[u'example text']
[u'example text', u'Another text']
```

it's as if the print command was part of the loop when i clearly put it outside , what am i doing wrong? This nippet of code is basically filtering some words , if they are in the first array they get put in another variable and if they are not they get added to variable "lista" , they i want to print lista to see all the words in  that array.

Comment: Possibly you've used a mixture of spaces and tabs for indentation, which is likely to cause Python to think that parts of your code are not indented to the level they visually appear to be.  If your editor doesn't have a "show invisibles" or similar feature that lets you see the difference between a space and a tab, get a better editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if i.text in noreportar:
        noreportables.append(i.text)

    else:
        lista.append(i.text)
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code! Adding some text to indicate how this best answers the question will improve the long-term value of the answer and help prevent it from being deleted during review.

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper Was right

It was an indetation issue , there were a lot of spaces and tabs randombly screwing my code.